# ExtJS 4 treepanel with checkbox issue

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

We are using treepanel with check box in our application.It seems like:

> var treepanel = {
>       id : 'tree',
>       xtype : 'treepanel',
>       store : layerStore,
>       rootVisible : false,
>       listeners : {
>       checkchange : function(node,check){
>       if(node.get('id') == 'teacher'){
>       alert('you have selected teacher node');
>       }else if(node.get('id') == 'student'){ alert('you have selected student node'); }
>       }
>       }
>       };

LayerStore code:

```
var layerStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore',{
root : {
children : [
{
text : 'teacher layer',
id : 'teacher',
checked : false
},{
text : 'Student layer',
id : 'student',
checked : false
}]
}
```

});

Now,i am getting the alert message when we check on the particular checkbox.My problem is that if we uncheck the checkbox then it has to display the alert like you has unselected a particular layer.Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quess You have to change your 'checkchange' handler to this:

```
checkchange : function(node,check){
  var s = (!check && 'un' || '' ) + 'selected';

  if(node.get('id') == 'teacher'){
    alert('you have '+s+' teacher node');
  }else if(node.get('id') == 'student'){ alert('you have '+s+' student node'); }
}
```

Comment: Hi Molecule,i have an another doubt,if we select the parent node,it has to select the cild nodes under particular parent node.For eg: if we select teacher node then the child nodes under teacher node has to select.Is there any poosibility?If please help me.

Comment: Hi @Kiran. It is possible. You may play around with node.cascadeBy. For example node.cascadeBy(function(childNode){childNode.set('checked', check); tree.fireEvent('checkchange', childNode, check); }. Although you may have issues with nested nodes. This code may not affect not rendered nodes. In this case I suggest using node.expandChildren(true, function(){node.cascadeBy(function(childNode){childNode.set('checked', check); tree.fireEvent('checkchange', childNode, check); }}); I'll be happy if it helps

Comment: How to unselect when parent node is unselected.I just tried using node.cascadeBy(function(childNode){childNode.set('unchecked',!check)}; But no improvement.If you have any idea please share with us.